# Remove huge empty space before and after an equation

Tags: spacing, equations

I have this extract from a latex code to define several equations:

```
\begin{equation}
    \min C =  \sum_{t=0}^{Z} (x_t \cdot P^{HPmax} + P_t^{DemandEl}) \cdot \Delta t \cdot p_t \label{eq:objective_function}
\end{equation}

subject to:

\begin{align}
    &T^{min} \leq T^{Building}_t \leq T^{max} \label{eq:temperature_balance} \\
    &T^{Building}_t = T^{Building}_{t-1} + \frac{Q_t^{HP} - Q_t^{DemandSH} -  Q_t^{LossesSH}}{V^{UFH} \cdot  \rho^{Concrete} \cdot c^{Concrete}} \label{eq:temperature_difference_equation} \\
    &Q_t^{HP} = x_t \cdot P^{HPmax}  \cdot COP_t \cdot \Delta t \label{eq:heating_energy_HP} \\
    &h^{switchedOff}_t \leq h^{on}_{t-1} \label{eq:hp_switched_off_1}  \\
    &h^{switchedOff}_t \leq 1 - h^{on}_{t} \label{eq:hp_switched_off_2}  \\
    &h^{switchedOff}_t \geq h^{on}_{t-1} - h^{on}_{t} \label{eq:hp_switched_off_3} \\
    &k_t^{switchedOff} =   \sum_{\tau=0}^{t} h_\tau^{switchedOff} \label{eq:hp_switched_off_4} \\
     &k^{switchedOff}_t \leq n^{switchedOff} \label{eq:hp_switched_off_5} \\
    &x_t \leq h^{on}_{t} \label{eq:hp_min_mod_1} \\
    &x_t \geq h^{on}_{t} \cdot mod^{min} \label{eq:hp_min_mod_2} \\
    &x_t \in [0,1], h^{switchedOff}_t \in \{0,1\}, h^{on}_{t} \in \{0,1\} \label{eq:non_negativity} 
\end{align}
```

The big problem is, that before and after the first equation, that I define separately such that I can add the text "subject to" underneath it, there is a huge empty space that I would like to eliminate. Here is the screenshot:
[image]

How can I reduce the empty space?

**Update**: Here is the main latex file:

```
\documentclass[5p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{amssymb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%
\usepackage{acro}
\include{sections/00_acro}
\graphicspath{{figures/}}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{framed} % Framing content
\usepackage{multicol} % Multiple columns environment
\usepackage{nomencl} % Nomenclature package
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{afterpage}


%Test new equation system display
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools,kantlipsum}
\newenvironment{AllowDisplayBreaks}{\allowdisplaybreaks}{\ignorespacesafterend}
\newcommand\stxt[1]{\scriptscriptstyle\textup{#1}}


%Define the color of the links
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\definecolor{myColor}{RGB}{0, 0.0, 0} 

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=myColor,
    citecolor=myColor,
    urlcolor=myColor,
}


\journal{Applied Energy}


% Remove preprint submitted to Applied Energy and the date
\makeatletter
\def\ps@pprintTitle{
  \let\@oddhead\@empty
  \let\@evenhead\@empty
  \def\@oddfoot{}%
  \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot
}
\makeatother



\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{Title}


\author[1]{A}
\author[1]{B}


\address[1]{Address1}

\begin{abstract}
\input{sections/00_abstract}
\end{abstract}

\begin{comment}
%%Graphical abstract
\begin{graphicalabstract}
\includegraphics{grabs}
\end{graphicalabstract}

%%Research highlights
\begin{highlights}
\item Research highlight 1
\item Research highlight 2
\end{highlights}
\end{comment}

\begin{keyword}
%% keywords here, in the form: keyword \sep keyword
keyword 1 \sep keyword 2 \sep keyword 3 \sep keyword 4 \sep keyword 5 
%% PACS codes here, in the form: \PACS code \sep code
%\PACS 0000 \sep 1111
%% MSC codes here, in the form: \MSC code \sep code
%% or \MSC[2008] code \sep code (2000 is the default)
%MSC 0000 \sep 1111
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

%% \linenumbers

\input{sections/00_nomecl}
\input{sections/01_intro}
\input{sections/02_related_work}
\input{sections/03_optimization_problem_for_the_building}
\input{sections/04_immitation_learning_for_building_control}
\input{sections/05_results}
\input{sections/06_conclusion}
\input{sections/ending}


\thispagestyle{empty} % Remove page number and header/footer on the first page


%% If you have bibdatabase file and want bibtex to generate the
%% bibitems, please use
%%
 \bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num} 
 \bibliography{refs}

%% else use the following coding to input the bibitems directly in the
%% TeX file.

% \begin{thebibliography}{00}

% %% \bibitem{label}
% %% Text of bibliographic item

% \bibitem{}

% \end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `elsarticle-template-num.tex'.
```

Comment: Where do you prefer the break? In the middle of the align?

Comment: Unrelated you should probably use `\mathrm{....}` or `\textup{....}` on all those names in `^{...}` (aka use `^{\textup{...}}` not `^{...}` that makes it easier to read.

Comment: An align is not allowed to be page/column broken unless you tell it to.

Comment: Note that you problably do not want to have blank lines around `sublect to` as that phrase is not a new paragraph.

Comment: never leave a blank line before a display it produces a white empty line of text (it is not vertical space and is not dropped at a page break)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks for your comment. What do you mean by "never leave a blank line before a display"? Where am I doing this and how can I avoid it

Comment: You have a blank line in the source before `\begin{equation}` and `\begin{align}` both are wrong. (if you search this site for "blank line before display" you will find this is a common error

Comment: @mickep: Thanks for your comment. Actually, it does not matter where the break is. Maybe the text will change such that the exact position should be determined dynamically. But I definitely don't want  the huge empty space

Comment: but the big space at the bottom is because you have not used `\allowdisplaybreaks` and there is not space for the whole alignment in the first column

Comment: But then the suggested code by @daleif is _the LaTeX answer_. Since you did not provide code that show the problem, he had to come up with some dummy text. I in fact think you are a bit rude in your comment to his answer.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks for your comment. I now removed the empty line and it results in Equation (1) being shifted to be bottom of the page. Thus, there is still a huge empty space before the Equation (1)

Comment: As you have not provided an example that shows the problem it's hard to give specific advice, just general comments

Comment: @mickep: Thanks for your comment. Well i definitely did not want to sound rude and I am still thankful for every comment and answer. But the "solution" is definitely not the one I am looking for. As written in the comment, there are a lot of issues with it and thus the solution is not really useful for me. I would like to try another approach without the integration of many further packages and without  `\kant[2]` and `\vspace*{12cm}`

Comment: @PeterBe you completely misunderstood the point of the vspace and kant that is making an example document and is only needed as you did not provide an example. It is not expected that you have either of those when you use the solution. You could still now edit your question and provide an example.

Comment: It says `LaTeX Error: Option clash for package geometry`, as mentioned you don't need any of the packages from my answer, only amsmth. Do yourself a favor: clean up that preamble and use only those you need. Perhaps even write small comment above each explaining what this is used for. Presumably elsarticle is also loading geometry, as mentioned it is not relevant to the solution, I only added it because your math gets super wide with those superscripts.

Comment: The code added is completly unrelated to the question and no one can run it but you. Make a small self contained 1-page document that does not load dozens of unrelated packages and shows the problem.  The point of posting code is to be _an example of the problem_ and to allow people to test answers. posting code that stops at `\input{sections/00_abstract}` does not help anyone help you/

Comment: never use `\include` in the preamble `\include{sections/00_acro}` should be `\input`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks for your comment. Regarding the code: I use a template that consists of 5 documents some of which have more than 1500 lines. I don't think it is useful to upload it (and I don't even know if I am allowed to upload it as it is from a publisher of journals). This is why I just included the main latex file such that you can see the packages that I am using and the structure of the document.

Comment: @daleif: Thanks a lot for your comment. "Do yourself a favor: clean up that preamble and use only those you need. Perhaps even write small comment above each explaining what this is used for. ". I think I need all of the packages. I am using a template with predefined packages (that I am most probably not allowed to delete) and I manually added several others because I needed them. So there is nothing to clean up.

Comment: Your original document does not matter, but _you_ should post an example of the problem you are asking about. If we just take your fragment and add it to an article class document then there will be no bad page break and no large space. Anyone answering has to guess some additional text to make your problem appear and you dismissed the answer posted for doing exactly that.

Comment: You certainly do not need xcolor or hyperref twice, and do you really need lipsum in your real document?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is what I would do (though I'd be using smaller text indicices)

The `AllowDisplayBreaks` env is just so we can add this locally. Tip: `\\*` discourage a page/column break.

I use `\stxt` to format the textual superscripts, given the size of these I choose to make the even smaller.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools,kantlipsum}
\newenvironment{AllowDisplayBreaks}{\allowdisplaybreaks}{\ignorespacesafterend}
\newcommand\stxt[1]{\scriptscriptstyle\textup{#1}}
\begin{document}

% just to force a column break

\vspace*{12cm}

\kant[2]

\begin{equation}
    \min C =  \sum_{t=0}^{Z} (x_t \cdot P^{\stxt{HPmax}} + P_t^{\stxt{DemandEl}}) \cdot \Delta t \cdot p_t \label{eq:objective_function}
\end{equation}
%
subject to:
%
\begin{AllowDisplayBreaks}
  \begin{align}
    &T^{\stxt{min}} \leq T^{\stxt{Building}}_t \leq T^{\stxt{max}} \label{eq:temperature_balance} \\
    &T^{\stxt{Building}}_t = T^{\stxt{Building}}_{t-1} + \frac{Q_t^{\stxt{HP}} - Q_t^{\stxt{DemandSH}} -  Q_t^{\stxt{LossesSH}}}{V^{\stxt{UFH}} \cdot  \rho^{\stxt{Concrete}} \cdot c^{\stxt{Concrete}}} \label{eq:temperature_difference_equation} \\
    &Q_t^{\stxt{HP}} = x_t \cdot P^{\stxt{HPmax}}  \cdot COP_t \cdot \Delta t \label{eq:heating_energy_HP} \\
    &h^{\stxt{switchedOff}}_t \leq h^{\stxt{on}}_{t-1} \label{eq:hp_switched_off_1}  \\
    &h^{\stxt{switchedOff}}_t \leq 1 - h^{\stxt{on}}_{t} \label{eq:hp_switched_off_2}  \\
    &h^{\stxt{switchedOff}}_t \geq h^{\stxt{on}}_{t-1} - h^{\stxt{on}}_{t} \label{eq:hp_switched_off_3} \\
    &k_t^{\stxt{switchedOff}} =   \sum_{\tau=0}^{t} h_\tau^{\stxt{switchedOff}} \label{eq:hp_switched_off_4} \\
    &k^{\stxt{switchedOff}}_t \leq n^{\stxt{switchedOff}} \label{eq:hp_switched_off_5} \\
    &x_t \leq h^{\stxt{on}}_{t} \label{eq:hp_min_mod_1} \\
    &x_t \geq h^{\stxt{on}}_{t} \cdot mod^{\stxt{min}} \label{eq:hp_min_mod_2} \\
    &x_t \in [0,1], h^{\stxt{switchedOff}}_t \in \{0,1\}, h^{\stxt{on}}_{t} \in \{0,1\} \label{eq:non_negativity} 
  \end{align}
\end{AllowDisplayBreaks}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have to admit that your solution is extremely bad. First of all, I think because of `\kant[2]`, some text from another source is added that has nothing to do with my article. Moreover, your suggested approach just shifted the empty white space. Altough in the formular itself it was not visible, but on other parts of the document a huge empty space was introduced. Can you maybe think of a solution without all these new packages and especially without `\kant[2]` and `\vspace*{12cm}`

Comment: @PeterBe `\kant` and `\vspace` are just used to generate a break in the align environment. It's to illustrate the solution, not part of the solution.

Comment: @PeterBe daleif used vspace and lipsum because you had failed to provide an example that shows the problem, the bad column break relies on all the text you show in teh image which is unreasonable to expect people to type in, and kandlipsum is just approximating that.

Comment: To format subscripts and superscripts I wrote the package [altsubsup](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/altsubsup). It allows to write `T^[min]` so `min` is formatted with `\text`. This can be change with `\SetAltSubSupCommands{\stxt}` to use your macro `\stxt` in place of `\text`.

Comment: @jlab: Thanks for your comment. I might consider this altough I don't see it as a big problem having the superscripts the way I use it.

Comment: @jlab and `\text` is totally the wrong command to use here. It should never be used in such a context. The textual sub or superscript should always be upright, `\text` is not

Comment: When using the solution I also get an error "LaTeX Error: Option clash for package geometry." thrown by the line `\usepackage{mathtools,kantlipsum}`

Comment: It's not obvious for me that `\text` should not be used in superscript. Anyway the command used by the package altsubsup can be changed by the user.

Comment: @PeterBe I'd like to see that code, update your question, do not delete what you have, but add the example that now gives error on that line.

Comment: @jlab Simple `\textit{Foo $\text{bar}$}` many users think `\text` gives upright text, it does not, it switch to the current textual context. So in a standard theorem it will be italics. Users should use a solution that always give upright, not just in some contexts.

Comment: @PeterBe you don't need any of the packages in my example, just `amsmath` which you are loading already.

Comment: @daleif: Thanks for your comments. I really appreciate it. I updated the question and posted the main latex file

Comment: @daleif: Thanks for your comments. Now when I remove the packages and the `\kant[2]` and `\vspace*{12cm}` command your answer seems to work. Thanks a lot for your help. I really appreciate it.